# Trouble with Debian Jessie, NVIDIA driver, Bumblebee and primusrun on Dell Vostro ultrabook

Tags: debian, nvidia, bumblebee

I am trying to install NVIDIA driver for my geforce 830m. My computer is a Dell Vostro 5480 with Intel HD Graphics 4400, and I can't disable the Intel graphs on BIOS so I presume that I need to use BUMBLEBEE library.

My current Kernel version is 3.16.0-4-amd64 over a Debian Linux 8 O.S

My /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
    deb http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
    deb-src http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
```

I have installed Bumblebee so I can run sucessfully optirun, but primusrun simple doesn't work:

```
    $ primusrun glxgears 
    Falha de segmentação (segmentation fault)
```

Edit: Ok so I follow the debian jessie-backport tutorial about installing bumblebee and it didn't work. Then I made some changes that I will share it here:

1. Add this to the end of the file /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

   ```
   Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Default Screen"
    Device "DiscreteNvidia"
   EndSection
   ```
2. On file /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf we made two changes. First, in section [blumblebeed] let Driver be equal to blank

   ```
   Driver =
   ```

   Second, in section [driver-nvidia] ensure that

   ```
   KernelDriver=nvidia-current
   ```
3. You need install or reinstall (don't ask me why) the following libs:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx
   ```
4. Make sure that you had downgraded the "intel-debian-issue" libdrm from 2.4.58 to 2.4.56. libs
5. Test the software

   ```
   sudo optirun -vv glxheads

   sudo primusrun glxheads
   ```
6. Verify if you had changed line on the file /etc/default/grub for:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet rcutree.rcu_idle_gp_delay=1"
   ```
7. On Steam, just click right button on a game then properties then SET LAUNCH OPTIONS and choose for

   ```
   optirun %COMMAND%

   primusrun %COMMAND%
   ```